# pandas how to truncate minutes, seconds pandas.tslib.Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, truncate, seconds

I work with Cloudera VM 5.2 and pandas 0.18.0.

I have the following data

```
adclicksDF = pd.read_csv('/home/cloudera/Eglence/ad-clicks.csv',
               parse_dates=['timestamp'],
       skipinitialspace=True).assign(adCount=1)

adclicksDF.head(n=5)
Out[107]: 
            timestamp  txId  userSessionId  teamId  userId  adId   adCategory  \
0 2016-05-26 15:13:22  5974           5809      27     611     2  electronics   
1 2016-05-26 15:17:24  5976           5705      18    1874    21       movies   
2 2016-05-26 15:22:52  5978           5791      53    2139    25    computers   
3 2016-05-26 15:22:57  5973           5756      63     212    10      fashion   
4 2016-05-26 15:22:58  5980           5920       9    1027    20     clothing   



   adCount  
0        1  
1        1  
2        1  
3        1  
4        1
```

Datatype fields are

```
for col in adclicksDF:
    print(col)
    print(type(adclicksDF[col][1]))


timestamp
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
txId
<class 'numpy.int64'>
userSessionId
<class 'numpy.int64'>
teamId
<class 'numpy.int64'>
userId
<class 'numpy.int64'>
adId
<class 'numpy.int64'>
adCategory
<class 'str'>
adCount
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

I want to truncate minutes and seconds in Timestamp.

I tried

```
adclicksDF["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(adclicksDF["timestamp"],format='%Y-%m-%d %H')

adclicksDF.head(n=5)
Out[110]: 
            timestamp  txId  userSessionId  teamId  userId  adId   adCategory  \
0 2016-05-26 15:13:22  5974           5809      27     611     2  electronics   
1 2016-05-26 15:17:24  5976           5705      18    1874    21       movies   
2 2016-05-26 15:22:52  5978           5791      53    2139    25    computers   
3 2016-05-26 15:22:57  5973           5756      63     212    10      fashion   
4 2016-05-26 15:22:58  5980           5920       9    1027    20     clothing   

   adCount  
0        1  
1        1  
2        1  
3        1  
4        1
```

This doesn't truncate minutes and seconds.

How can I truncate minutes and seconds?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
adclicksDF["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(adclicksDF["timestamp"])
                            .apply(lambda x: x.replace(minute=0, second=0))


print (adclicksDF)
            timestamp  txId  userSessionId  teamId  userId  adId   adCategory
0 2016-05-26 15:00:00  5974           5809      27     611     2  electronics
1 2016-05-26 15:00:00  5976           5705      18    1874    21       movies
2 2016-05-26 15:00:00  5978           5791      53    2139    25    computers
3 2016-05-26 15:00:00  5973           5756      63     212    10      fashion
4 2016-05-26 15:00:00  5980           5920       9    1027    20     clothing

print (type(adclicksDF.ix[0, 'timestamp']))
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

If need output as `string` use [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
adclicksDF["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(adclicksDF["timestamp"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')
print (adclicksDF)
       timestamp  txId  userSessionId  teamId  userId  adId   adCategory
0  2016-05-26 15  5974           5809      27     611     2  electronics
1  2016-05-26 15  5976           5705      18    1874    21       movies
2  2016-05-26 15  5978           5791      53    2139    25    computers
3  2016-05-26 15  5973           5756      63     212    10      fashion
4  2016-05-26 15  5980           5920       9    1027    20     clothing

print (type(adclicksDF.ix[0, 'timestamp']))
<class 'str'>
```

EDIT:

Better solution is use `dt.floor` like in answer of [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44761671/2901002)

Comment: Take a look at Alex' answer - you could add this to your answer because it is a more elegant and faster solution.

Comment: @pansen - I connot do it, because cannot copy another answers. But I aggre it is better solution.

Comment: Right, you're correct. But you could reference the solution as a hint for new users which come across this question.

Answer (score 2):

`pd.Timestamp` has a [floor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html#pandas.Series.dt.floor) resolution method since 0.18

```
adclicksDF["timestamp"] = adclicksDF.timestamp.dt.floor('h')
```

Comment: This should be the prefered solution since it is more elegant (avoiding `apply` and using pandas builtin `floor`) and roughly 50 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pd.to_datetime(adclicksDF.timestamp).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')
```

After assignment:

```
adclicksDF.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(adclicksDF.timestamp).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')

adclicksDF
```

[image]